# Export (.ical) only Attending or Maybe Attending events from Facebook

Tags: facebook, export, facebook-events, icalendar

By default, Facebook exports `Attending`, `(Maybe) Attending` and also events that I haven't replied (RSVPed) to yet. This results in an event spam in my Google Calendar.

Is there a way to get a ical feed of only the events that I have marked to `Attend` or `(Maybe) Attend`?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: http://www.fbcal.com/

Comment: I don't see the calendar that only exports "Attending" and "Maybe" events from the quoted page.

Answer (score 1):

[Konscript](http://freedom.konscript.com/) aims at solving this exact problem.

Comment: Have you used this service? Any affiliation?

Comment: I'm not affiliated in any way with the project. I've used it in the past and it's always done a good job, although recently I found it didn't work quite as reliably.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run PHP somewhere, you can use this proxy to filter the calendar FB provides: https://code.google.com/p/fbcal/

Comment: Please disclose if you are affiliate with the project.  Thanks!